# How can I dynamically call an <img> alt attribute?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website, where I had inserted the following code into the `header.php` file, in order to dynamically call the Custom Logo:

```php
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'has_custom_logo' ) ) {
    has_custom_logo();
} 
?>
```

Whilst this worked, I had problems with the resizing of dimensions.  Consequently, I replaced the code with the following code:

```
<?php 
    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'thumbnail' ); 
        if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
            echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $logo[0] ) .'">';
        } 
        else {
            echo '<h1>'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'</h1>'; 
        }
?>
```

This alternative code also called the Custom Logo, as well as allowing me to alter the Custom Logo dimensions via the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` parameters.

The down side is that it strips the HTML `img` output of its `Alt` Attribute.

Is there a way to dynamically call the `Alt` attribute?  I assume I would need to append it to the `echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $logo[0] ) .'">';` entry.

**Latest Code:**

```
<?php
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );    
$custom_logo_attr = get_post_meta( $custom_logo_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );


    if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($custom_logo_id, 'thumbnail', false, $custom_logo_attr);
    } 

    else {
        echo '<h1>'. get_bloginfo( 'name' ) .'</h1>'; 
    }               
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference for [`get_custom_logo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/), you can get the logo image alt data via [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).

```php
/*
 * If the logo alt attribute is empty, get the site title and explicitly
 * pass it to the attributes used by wp_get_attachment_image().
 */
$image_alt = get_post_meta( $custom_logo_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
if ( empty( $image_alt ) ) {
  $custom_logo_attr['alt'] = get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );
}

/*
 * If the alt attribute is not empty, there's no need to explicitly pass
 * it because wp_get_attachment_image() already adds the alt attribute.
 */
$html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
  wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, $custom_logo_attr )
);
```

The [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) function accepts an `$attr` [parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/#parameters).

```
wp_get_attachment_image( int $attachment_id, string|array $size = 'thumbnail',  
                         bool $icon = false, string|array $attr = '' )
```

> $attr
>   (string|array) (Optional) Attributes for the image markup.
>   Default value: ''

Comment: Not sure if I am doing something wrong but when I enter your suggested code, the image no longer displays.

Comment: Hm, are you getting any errors? Are you still outputting `$logo`? If possible, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46714978/edit) and add your updated code after your original post.

Comment: I've just checked the Source Code and nothing is outputted with your suggested code apart from the empty `<div>` container, in which I placed the code.

Comment: How are you echoing the HTML that's generated (`$html` in the example above)?

Comment: I have inserted:  `echo '<img src="'. esc_url( $html ) .'">';` I assume there is an errror with this code?

Comment: In the example I posted, `$html` consists of an `<a>` tag and an `<img>`. I'd try just echoing it directly.

Comment: Sorry but do you mean by echoing the image's URL itself?

Comment: I mean like `echo $html;`. That string already includes an image tag, so injecting it into another image tag will create invalid HTML.

Comment: Oh right.  I got you.  I changed the code slightly from `$html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a>',
  esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),` to `$html = sprintf( '<img src="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">%2$s</a></img>',` but cannot quite figure out what to replace `%1$s` with as to dynamically call the Custom Logo.  I have tried 'the_custom_logo' and 'has_custom_logo' but to no success.

Comment: Now you're injecting the link url into an image tag. The `wp_get_attachment_image()` function returns an image tag. You don't need to include the image tag in your string. If you don't want the link, just `echo wp_get_attachment_image($custom_logo_id, 'full', false, $custom_logo_attr);`.

Comment: Thanks for your time with this.  I have inserted your suggested echo, which does call the image.  I am not sure if I am overlooking something but I still cannot seem to generate the `alt` attribute.  I inserted the following: `$custom_logo_attr = get_post_meta( $custom_logo_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );` but to no success.  Think I have confused myself a little bit here.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46714978/edit) and add your updated code after your original post. I'm having a hard time keeping up with what you've changed.

Answer (score -2):

Create a subfolder in php drop your image into the folder, after that just drag and drop the link, it should work.